# Why would you use the ternary operator without assigning a value for the "true" condition (x = x ?: 1)

Tags: c, gcc, android-emulator, conditional-operator, qemu

In the Android open-source qemu code I ran across this line of code:

```
machine->max_cpus = machine->max_cpus ?: 1; /* Default to UP */
```

Is this just a confusing way of saying:

```
if (machine->max_cpus) {
   ; //do nothing
} else {
 machine->max_cpus = 1;
}
```

If so, wouldn't it be clearer as:

```
if (machine->max_cpus == 0) machine->max_cpus = 1;
```

Interestingly, this compiles and works fine with gcc, but doesn't compile on http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/ .

Comment: Wait, what?! … that looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @Konrad - probably not. The comment suggests the line sets a default - if "max_cpus is not set, set the default value".

Comment: If it is legal, I would avoid it because it looks too much like it might be a bug. Here we having a big discussion about it, proving that it would have been clearer to use the if statement.

Comment: @Mac: In that case I would expect a commend à la “GNU extension syntax: …”. But you’re probably right.

Comment: @Konrad: Nah. In a large compiler-specific code base, you're hardly going to comment every single use of an extension with "this is an extension". Granted, this is a particularly tricky one for the reader to find by Google search, compared with, say, `__builtin_clz`, or (in C++) `long long`...

Comment: "wouldn't it be clearer as". Yes. But maybe not so much if it had been `machine->max_cpus = arguments->max_cpus ?: 1;`. Could be the result of over-using an idiom that works OK in some cases, but not others.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is [permitted](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.4/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals) in GNU as an obscure extension to C

> 5.7 Conditionals with Omitted Operands
>
> The middle operand in a conditional
>   expression may be omitted. Then if the
>   first operand is nonzero, its value is
>   the value of the conditional
>   expression.
>
> Therefore, the expression
>
> ```
>  x ? : y
> ```
>
> has the value of x if that is nonzero;
>   otherwise, the value of y.
>
> This example is perfectly equivalent
>   to
>
> ```
>  x ? x : y
> ```
>
> In this simple case, the ability to
>   omit the middle operand is not
>   especially useful. When it becomes
>   useful is when the first operand does,
>   or may (if it is a macro argument),
>   contain a side effect. Then repeating
>   the operand in the middle would
>   perform the side effect twice.
>   Omitting the middle operand uses the
>   value already computed without the
>   undesirable effects of recomputing it.

As you can probably guess, avoiding this is recommended for readability and portability reasons. I'm honestly surprised to see such a grammar-incompatible extension to C.

Comment: Interesting. This seems both incredibly useful as a syntactic feature, and incredibly obscure to understand.

Comment: I agree. But there are many things one could add to C to make it more elegant, I'm surprise a compiler vendor would explicitly make such a permissive change to the C grammar. If this was C++, that's another story since it used to be a jungle of incompatibility.

Comment: interresting. that became ?? in C#   "x if x is not null, otherwise y" => c ?? y

Comment: @Potatoswatter: not really, since presumably `max_cpus` is not boolean valued. `||` has no way of evaluating to `3` if the prior value was `3`.

Comment: Since this idiom behaves differently from a `ternary conditional` and more like a `logical or` in most languages, I propopse it's henceforth called the `ternarator`

Comment: I wish more compilers supported this incredibly useful extension.  I don't think that it is obscure at all if you know what it means, it actually is more expressive.

Comment: I'd like to add that clang also supports this (as with many GNU extensions) unless run with -pedantic.

Comment: It's so obscure I didn't have any idea how I can search for this at first.

Answer (score 11):

This is a [GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_4.html#SEC70) that means "if the condition is true, use it, else use this other value", so

```
machine->max_cpus = machine->max_cpus ?: 1;
```

is shorthand for

```
machine->max_cpus = machine->max_cpus ? machine->max_cpus : 1;
```

although if the conditional has side-effects, it will only be run once

Answer (score 7):

Using gcc's -pedantic flag, it does say

> foo.c:5: warning: ISO C forbids
>   omitting the middle term of a ?:
>   expression

Answer (score 4):

It's a [GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Conditionals.html), and it gets more interesting and useful when the condition has side effects.

In this case, yes, I for one would agree it's obscure more than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

The K&R BNF shows an expression is required between "?" and ":".  I don't think gcc should be compiling that without a diagnostic.

Comment: It's a non-standard gcc extension I believe. Best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

There's another useful case for this -- the elimination of intermediate variables when calling a function or method that might return nil, that we wish to avoid calling twice. For example (Objective-C), suppose we want to unpack a file into an array if it exists, otherwise return an empty array.

```
- (NSArray*)hydrateBacklogFromFile:(NSString *path)
{
    NSArray *backlog = @[];
    NSData *backlogData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    if (backlogData)
    {
        backlog = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:backlogData] ?: backlog;
    }
    return backlog;
}
```

The alternatives are less concise.

```
- (NSArray*)hydrateBacklogFromFile:(NSString *path)
{
    NSArray *backlog = @[];
    NSData *backlogData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    if (backlogData)
    {
        NSArray *tempArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:backlogData];
        if (tempArray != nil)
        {
            backlog = tempArray;
        }
    }
    return backlog;
}
```

Or uglier with multiple returns etc.

```
- (NSArray*)hydrateBacklogFromFile:(NSString *path)
{
    NSData *backlogData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    if (backlogData)
    {
        NSArray *tempArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:backlogData];
        if (tempArray != nil)
        {
            return tempArray;
        }
    }
    return @[];
}
```

So it's useful syntactic sugar that I find fairly readable. The downsides are

- Implicit conversion of a pointer to a bool. This is a long-standing C
  convention, but most modern languages disallow it, complicating
  any porting efforts.
- As others have said it's also a non-standard extension, so it should
  be avoided if portability is a consideration at all.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the other answers do not answer the question in the title and also taking the tag `c` into account. Therefore I add another answer.

I use this syntax to prevent my code from getting ugly through if-statements.

```
foo(1) == TRUE ?: error_quit("foo(1) failed");
foo(2) == TRUE ?: error_quit("foo(2) failed");
foo(3) == TRUE ?: error_quit("foo(3) failed");
foo(4) == TRUE ?: error_quit("foo(4) failed");
```

You can see the actual function call right in the beginning of the line. Compared it to the versions below, where the leading `if` obstructs the direct view of the function call.

```
if (foo(1) == FALSE) error_quit("foo(1)" failed");
if (foo(2) == FALSE) error_quit("foo(2)" failed");
if (foo(3) == FALSE) error_quit("foo(3)" failed");    
if (foo(4) == FALSE) error_quit("foo(4)" failed");
```

or even harder to read:

```
if (foo(1) == FALSE){
  error_quit("foo(1)" failed");
}

if (foo(2) == FALSE){
  error_quit("foo(2)" failed");
}

if (foo(3) == FALSE){
  error_quit("foo(3)" failed");
}

if (foo(4) == FALSE){
  error_quit("foo(4)" failed");
}
```