# Strange use of conditional operator

Tags: c++, c, conditional-operator

I am currently porting some Unix code to Windows and came across a rather strange use of the conditional operator which is not valid syntax according to Visual Studio (either 2010 or 2012).

Copied and pasted without modification:

```
filename = filename ? : h->filename;
```

There is no condition! I assume it is either a check against an empty string (of the `const char*` sort), or against null & empty, as I can't think of anything else it can be.

Has anybody seen this before? Thank you.

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806255/why-would-you-use-the-ternary-operator-without-assigning-a-value-for-the-true : *"This is permitted in GNU as an obscure extension to C"*

Comment: Thank you all for a great set of answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a gcc extension.

```
x = a ? : b;
```

is *almost* the same as

```
x = a ? a : b;
```

except for the fact that `a` is only evaluated *once*, which is useful if `a` has any side effects or is expensive to evaluate.

Answer (score 2):

The given code works similar to the following code in this particular context,

```
if (!filename) {
    filename = h->filename;
}
```

Also note that in this example filename and h->filename are two different variables. filename is an ordinary variable and h->filename is the member variable of a structure.