# Java ternary operator with empty clause

Tags: java, ternary-operator

This question is more for my curiosity than anything else.

I often employ Java's ternary operator to write shorter code. I have been wondering, however, whether it is possible to use it if one of the `if` or `else` conditions are empty. In more details:

```
int x = some_function();
if (x > 0)
    x--;
else
    x++;
```

can be written as `x = (x > 0) ? x-1 : x+1;`

But is it possible to write `if (x > 0) x-1;` as a ternary expression with an empty *else* clause?

Comment: The ternary operator resolves to a value. It's not a block.

Comment: Nitpick: Shouldn't `x = (x > 0) ? x-- : x++;` be `x = (x > 0) ? --x : ++x;`? Or even better: `x = (x > 0) ? x - 1 : x + 1;`

Comment: No. Let the compiler deal with those semantic issues.

Comment: Aaack.  Please don't write code that assigns to a variable and uses a post-increment or pre-increment on the same variable.  It gives me a headache.

Comment: Sorry about the unary increments. Edited it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> But is it possible to write `if (x > 0) x--;` as a ternary expression with an empty else clause?

No, the conditional operator *requires* three operands. If you wanted, you could do this:

```
x = (x > 0) ? x - 1 : x;
```

...but *(subjectively)* I think clarity suffers.

Comment: I see countless x=x assignments taking place in some place. seems kinda silly and inefficient if that can happen.

Comment: I agree, clarity certainly suffers. I was curious about Java's take on it since in C (using GCC compiler), one may write something like `x = (x>0) ?: x+1;`

Comment: @ChthonicProject: Interesting, [apparently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2806311/157247) that's a GNU-specific extension. I did [check the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) earlier; didn't see anything saying either of the second and third operands is optional (in Java).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't know it was GNU-specific, and would have tried it on other platforms too ... and suffered! This was a big help (hence the upvote).