# Javascript ternary operator with empty 2nd expression

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I've looked at somewhat similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687589/java-ternary-operator-with-empty-clause) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932754/ternary-operators-in-javascript-without-an-else) but they are answering a different question as they look at assignment operations. For example my code is

`!item.completed ? addTask(item) : null`

as I would like to execute a certain function if condition is met or do nothing if it's not met. My question is what would be considered a good practice to pass as an 'empty' 2nd expression?

I saw a lot of people using `null`, on the other hand I think that using an empty string `''` is also a valid option as since there is no assignment happening an empty string is faster to type and doesn't seem to have any cons.

Comment: The ternary operator isn't appropriate here if there is no third thing.  Just use an `if`.

Comment: why not just use if? if minification is your goal then '' is better

Comment: ternary is generally shorter and seems more readable to me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview but I can't transfer there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use [logical or `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_())

```
item.completed || addTask(item)
```

Comment: Never thought about the OR operator in this way, thank you for opening the new use for it

Answer (score 3):

I think this is not a good use of the ternary operator.

I'd either do:

```
if (!item.completed) addTask(item);
```

Or

```
!item.completed && addTask(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

`!item.completed && addTask(item);`

There's no point using a ternary if you don't need it.